# Show $g''=f$ on $[0, 1]$ with $g(x):=\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)f(t)dt$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x):=\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)f(t)dt$. I have to show that $g''=f$ on $[0,1]$.

How can I get the derivative of an integral?

Comment: By using the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus.)

Comment: Also: [Suppose $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ is continuous. Define $G(x)=\int_0^x(x-t)f(t)dt$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Prove $G''(x)=f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028118/suppose-f-bbbr-rightarrow-bbbr-is-continuous-define-gx-int-0xx-tf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, by fundamental theorem of calculus
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_0^xh(t)dt = h(x)$$
for any function $h$.

Using this repeatedly, we have,
$$g(x) = x\int_0^xf(t)dt-\int_0^xtf(t)dt$$
$$\implies g'(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt+xf(x)-xf(x)$$
$$\implies g''(x)=f(x)$$