# A function $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{3!}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^3f(t)dt$,$x \ge 0$.Show that $\varphi^{iv}(x) = f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> A function $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{3!}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^3f(t)dt$,$x \ge 0$.Show that $\varphi^{iv}(x)  = f(x) ,  x \ge 0$

I simply don't understand how to approach the problem.How do I raise a function $\varphi(x)$ to the power of $iv$ and then integrate it?

Comment: I think that $iv$ means the $4$-th derivative.

Comment: You should be able to prove the statement with [Cauchy's repeated integral formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: $\frac{1}{3!}(x-t)^3.f(x)$ is a continuous function so the antiderrivative $\varphi(x) =\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{3!}(x-t)^3.f(x)$ is a differentiable function so $\varphi'(x) = \frac{1}{3!}(x-t)^3f(x)$(by 2nd FTC F'(x) = f(x) ) . @jorge can you correct me, i am not sure how to use cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3028118/42969

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$ the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1{n!}\int_0^x (x-t)^nf(t)\,dt\right)$$
is equal to
\begin{align}
&\left(\frac1{n!}(x-t)^nf(t)\right)\Bigg|_{t=x}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x) - \left(\frac1{n!}(x-t)^nf(t)\right)\Bigg|_{t=0}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(0) + \frac1{n!} \int_0^x \frac{d}{dx}(x-t)^nf(t)\,dt\\
&\quad = \frac1{n!} \int_0^x n(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)\,dt = \frac1{(n-1)!} \int_0^x (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)\,dt.
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\varphi^{\mathrm{iv}}(x) &= \frac{d^4}{dx^4}\left(\frac1{3!}\int_0^x (x-t)^3f(t)\,dt\right)\\
&= \frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left(\frac1{2!}\int_0^x (x-t)^2f(t)\,dt\right)\\
&= \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac1{1!}\int_0^x (x-t)^1f(t)\,dt\right)\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1{0!}\int_0^x (x-t)^0f(t)\,dt\right)\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\right)\\
&= f(x).
\end{align}